# Discover SQL Server in network from Windows 10

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, network-programming

**The Situation**

We are selling a system that masures objects and visualizes them.
The system consists of a standalone hardware with embedded software and a .net application that can be installed on a Windows-PC.

The .net application visualizes and stores data on the local filesystem in a folder / file structure.

As some customers wanted to use the data from different places, we decided to switch our storing system to MSSQL.

The software is now able to run either in "server mode", what means it can connect to the hardware and store data on the MSSQL server, or in "client mode", what means it can connect to the MSSQL server to visualize data.

The MSSQL server can be installed on the same PC as our "server mode software", or on any other server inside the company net.

**The Funktion**

When starting the software, it is necessary to define the MSSQL server where the data is stored. As this address can change and we dont want our customers to handle IP-addresses, we want to give the customer the possibility to select the server from a combobox.

**The Problem**

We tried

```
public void findInstances(out List<string> v_server)
    {
        v_server = new List<string>();
        SqlDataSourceEnumerator l_instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        System.Data.DataTable l_table = l_instance.GetDataSources();
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow l_row in l_table.Rows)
        {
            v_server.Add((string)l_row["ServerName"] + "\\" + (string)l_row["InstanceName"]);
        }
        return;
    }
```

The table is always empty, meaning it has headers, but no rows.

Using

```
[System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources()
```

inside Windows PowerShell does not return anything.

**The parameters**

Dev machine has installed Windows 10 and MSSQL server 2008 R2 U3.

MSSQL Management Studio finds 9 instances in our network.

Application is in .net 4.0.

UDP 1434 and TCP 1433 on Dev machine are open.

PowerShell and Application tested as user and admin.

We tried to set the application to "full-trust", no change.

**The Question**

Why can't we find ANY instance inside our network? Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

When remote debugging the software on a Windows 7 machine, the table is NOT empty. It seems to be a Windows 10 or system configuration issue... I'm still searching.

**UPDATE 2**

It seems the problem comes from .net 4.6, which is included in Win10. There is a  [MS Connect thread](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1633740/system-data-sql-sqldatasourceenumerator-doesnt-work-on-windows-10-with-net-framework-4-x) abot this topic.

For us, this means we won't use SQL-browsing at the moment due to the risk customers could use .net 4.6.

As this is not a solution for the problem, I don't mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

[It could be a bug as reported here.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1633740/system-data-sql-sqldatasourceenumerator-doesnt-work-on-windows-10-with-net-framework-4-x)